# jQuery: How to select all radio buttons with a name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all radio buttons with a name, but I can only select the checked ones. For example this works:

```
$("input[@name='id']:checked").each(function() { // });
```

It selects all inputs with name id, which are checked (in this case one radio button). But I need all of them, as I need the not checked ones for this name, on this function.

This, for example, is not doing anything:

```
$("input[@name='id']").each(function()  { // });
```

What do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You no longer need the `@` in jQuery selectors.  That's what's causing your problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('input[name="yourName"]').each(function () { ... });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sFtdR/

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$(':input[type="radio"]').each(function(index){
     // YOUR CODE
});
```

above code will select all input element who's **type** attribute is **radio**.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$("input[name='id']").each(function()  { 
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```